# Double Intent Error

Tags: android

I have a problem regarding the code below, I have two buttons on my welcome screen. Each of the button links to different page, am I using the wrong code? Can you all guide me and correct me?? I am new android app development.

```
package com.example.testing;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private Boolean firstRun;
        //private Boolean accountRun;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if(sp.getBoolean("firstRun", true)){
                PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true);
                firstRun = true;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
                editor.commit();
            } else {
                firstRun = false;
            }

            this.initViews();
        }

        private void initViews(){
            Button btnAccount = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAccount);
            btnAccount.setOnClickListener(this);
            Button btnContinue = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);
            btnContinue.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, testingquestion1.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            i.putExtra("firstRun", firstRun);
            startActivity(i);

            Intent h = new Intent(this, testingquestion2.class);
            //h.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            //i.putExtra("firstRun", firstRun);
            startActivity(h);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not condition to check between which button is click.
To find that View arg0 is to be used. Try following code and add more logic as required for first run.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (btnAccount.getId() == (((Button)v).getId())){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, testingquestion1.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        i.putExtra("firstRun", firstRun);
        startActivity(i);
    } else (btnContinue.getId() == (((Button)v).getId())){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, testingquestion1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your code, but I am not able to change to arg0 as the error shown is "incompatible operand types View and int". Can you guide me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to run 2 intents on each button click for both buttons.  You want an if statement in there to see which button was pressed, and do one intent for btnAccount, and one for btnContinue.